# log4j2 - JVM input arguments lookup (jvmrunargs) does not work

Tags: jvm, lookup, log4j2

I have just started trying out log4j2 (I've been using log4j 1.2.X previously). Aside from the frustration of trying to figure out what is needed/valid for the configuration file (log4j2.xml), I have been unable to use the Java VM "lookup" capability supposedly supported by log4j2. As far as I can tell, I'm doing the right stuff - based on the information available from the log4j web site. Has anyone ever had any success with this?

Here are the basics of what I'm doing:

java class:
[which is using SLF4J to "bridge" to log4j]

```
package logger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Main {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("In main()");
  }

}
```

log4j2.xml:
[I'm trying to pass a log directory, configured elsewhere]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration status="INFO" strict="true">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="filename">${jvmrunargs:log_dir}/log.txt</Property>
  </Properties>

  <!-- APPENDERS -->
  <Appenders>
    <Appender type="File" name="File" fileName="${filename}">
      <Layout type="PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
      </Layout>
    </Appender>
  </Appenders>

  <!-- LOGGERS -->
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="File" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

This fails with multiple exceptions thrown by log4j:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/jo24447/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.7/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/jo24447/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2016-12-07 10:44:52,566 main ERROR FileManager (${jvmrunargs:log_dir}/log.txt) java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${jvmrunargs:log_dir}\log.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${jvmrunargs:log_dir}\log.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:258)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:238)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:530)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:603)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:226)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at logger.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)

2016-12-07 10:44:52,572 main ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class for plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender, element File. java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@1decca33] unable to create manager for [${jvmrunargs:log_dir}/log.txt] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@24cee99e]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:530)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:603)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:226)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at logger.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)

2016-12-07 10:44:52,575 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:882)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:874)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:498)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:239)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:530)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:603)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:620)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:226)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at logger.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)

2016-12-07 10:44:52,576 main ERROR Null object returned for File in Appenders.
2016-12-07 10:44:52,581 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "File" for logger config "root"
```

Here is the simple pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>logger</groupId>
  <artifactId>logger</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <compileSource>1.7</compileSource>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>

    <log4j.version>2.7</log4j.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.21</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Log4J 2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4J 2 to SLF4J bridge -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SLF4J -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${compileSource}</source>
          <target>${compileSource}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you writing your own slf4j to log4j bridge ? you could use the bridge provided by log4j itself. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html

Comment: This seems to be a dependency conflict. Could you please share your dependencies in this project ? pom.xml file or output of "mvn dependency:tree" command if you are using maven ?

Comment: Added the pom.xml listing.

Comment: Here is a minimal working sample of using log4j2 from one of my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/40955325/1849366

Comment: If you just want to use log4j2, all you need is log4j-api and log4j-core dependencies. And if you have any dependency jars which use slf4j logging, you need to add log4j-slf4j-impl so that those logs will be redirected to log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the JVM argument when launching your Java applicatio like :

```
java -Dlog_dir=/path/to/log/folder -jar your-application.jar
```

In your log4j2.xml, you can use the property like :

```
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_FOLDER">${sys:log_dir}</Property>
</Properties>
```